# How to detect iOS devices when cable is plugged or not (without adding USB to the charge)

Tags: ios

I understand that we could determine the battery status with `UIDeviceBatteryState` , but I can not find how to detect if only the cable is plugged to device or not (only 30-pin or Lightning is added to device).

As I checked with `UIDeviceBatteryState`, status always `UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged` in this case, no matter I plug the cable or not.

Maybe I have to use C to detect it? Any conclusion will be very helpful with me. Thanks

Comment: you want to know when the cable is plugged in to the device but not plugged in anywhere on the USB side? i don't think this possible. i don't even think the device can detect that at all, when there is no current.

Comment: actually i try to detect on hardware field (with C) if possible. I research in objective C and iOS libraries but can't get any conclusion, like you said.

Answer (score 4):

It's a hardware question.

A cable is basically just a set of wires that are not connected to each other. When you connect one end of the cable, but don't connect the other, nothing changes, because no circuit gets closed.

[image]

And although the Lightning cable has a chip inside, I believe it doesn't  get any power until both ends of the cable are connected to something.

Comment: Imaginable! Did you work with hardware before, or know any reference to work with hardware on iOS field? I know it is hard (or impossible) to work with 30-pin cable, but still find a way to work with the Lighting, which has a chip inside.

Comment: @dementiazz No, I didn't work with the hardware, but I know that there is public `ExternalAccessory` and private `IOKit` framework (it's public for OS X, but iOS apps linked with it will be rejected from the App Store).